# Raise an exception when parent fails to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've run into a gotcha when trying to create a parent and child at the same time. **I would think an exception should be raised when the associated parent fails to save, but it doesn't.**

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  validates_presence_of :parent, :name
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :child
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Notice the child saves and their is no visibility into the save issue with the parent:

```
parent = Parent.new
parent.valid?                         # => false
child = Child.create!(name: 'something', parent: parent) # => true
child.parent_id                       # => nil
child.reload.valid?                   # => false
```

An an invalid child has been created. Why is the `create!` method not calling `create!` on the parent as well so an exception is raised?

Its worth noting that When the same process is followed, but instead we start from the parent, we get the behavior I expect:

```
child = child.new
child.valid?                         # => false
parent = Parent.create!(name: 'something', child: child) # => ActiveRecord::Exception
parent.valid?                         # => false
```

I know some work arounds (e.g. `validates_associated :parent` on the child), but I'm trying to understand why Rails is behaving the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't know you're trying to save them at the same time. If you want to save them both at once, try [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

I would expect this to do what you want:

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  validates_presence_of :parent
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
  validates_presence_of :name

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, allow_destroy: true
end

parent = Parent.new children: [child]
parent.save!
```

Comment: Rails definitely knows you are trying to save them both at the same time because it saves the parent. Unfortunately, it uses .save and not .save! so if it works great, otherwise you wouldn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Why would the exception be raised? You are setting the `parent` and as far as the `child` is concerned, the `parent` exists (passing the validation) and it will not call the `create!` on the parent and IMO nor should it.

Your workaround is to validate on the `parent_id` instead of the `parent` or create the child via `parent.children.create!`. The latter will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: You cannot call create unless the parent is saved` if the parent is not persisted

Comment: Excuse me i have a question to you, Does not rails automatically put `not_null` constraint on the association field so that in this case DB will through an exception or should i put the constraint myself @AbM

Comment: @AmrAdel Rails does not add that constraint in the migration, since it supports optional `belongs_to` association. If you want to make it mandatory, you will have to add that constraint explicitly

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot.

Comment: But Rails does create the parent, it just creates the parent without the bang so you don't know that it actually failed to create. Had the parent passed validation, Rails would have saved it no problem.

Comment: Its also worth noting that if you did a parent.create!(child: child) it will validate the child and only save if it passes validation.

Answer (score 0):

change children to

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  validates_presence_of :parent, :id
end
```

It is as @AbM said you should put the constraint on some field, This will give you `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Id can't be blank` exception.

Comment: This will make it so you could not validate the child before saving to the database.